# SSRS Saving selections of input dropdowns

Tags: jquery, reporting-services

I have several reports that are consolidated into a dashboard, each report presents different data, but has the same drop down selections, or less. What I am I need it to do is remember the last selection and then when the next report is selected, the selection is remembered and then applied to all other reports... I thought about setting a Jquery cookie, but given how inflexible SSRS is I am not sure what my options are, not to mention I am hopeless with Jquery.

For example report 1 might have the following selections

**Location**

- Location 1
- Location 2

**Manager**

- Manager 1
- Manager 2

**Agents**

- Agents 1
- Agents 2

And then report 2 might have the following selections

**Location**

- Location 1
- Location 2

**Manager**

- Manager 1
- Manager 2

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't have to only use SELECT queries in SSRS. Part of your report run could include a query that updates a table with the selected value of the parameters. The parameters could then have a default that is set by a query that retrieves this value.

Using update and/or insert in your SSRS queries is probably not the recommended practice but it is possible.

If multiple people have access to run the report this could cause issues with the parameter default being the last value of the report run but not necessarily for the same person. You may be able to alleviate this by making use of the SSRS global for the current user.

Comment: If you want to see an example of this approach, there is one on Codeplex: http://rsparamlogcache.codeplex.com/

Comment: Nice idea, but in my case this will not work, I am running the site under IIS which impersonates a single account (have many different people accessing with different needs). Authentication to the reports is driven by LDAP code sitting above the reports.

Comment: Have you checked what the value of the SSRS global `User!UserID` is? It may still come out correctly, I'm not sure. I'd test it with your setup just in case.